# Run VBA macro in another workbook while using main workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks, call them A and B. I'm trying to combine some of the data from B into A. However, I need the macro in B to run, and update B before I incorporate the data in A.

I have been able to open workbook B, but I can't get the macro to run. The current code in workbook A is:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Clauric\Desktop\B.xlsm"
    Windows("B.xlsm").Activate
    Application.Run "C:\Users\Clauric\Desktop\B.xlsm"!A_Tour.A_Tour"
```

When I tried this code, I get

> Run-Time Error 1004 - Cannot run macro ... The macro may not be
>   available in this workbook or all macro may be disabled

I can run the macro if I launch it manually from B.xlsm, and I can run macros manually in workbook A, without any issues.

Is there any way that I can run the macro in B from A, so that the macro updates B?

Edit: Problem is similar, but solution marked as solving the problem does not work.

Solution is to call the macro when the workbook opens. This is the 2nd suggested solution to the other query.

Comment: I'm unclear on the problem here. If you open B.xlsm while in A.xlsx why can't you simply run *A_Tour* through the Macros dialog? Is it a **Private** sub procedure?

Comment: This syntax looks off: `"C:\Users\Clauric\Desktop\B.xlsm"!A_Tour.A_Tour"`. Change to `"C:\Users\Clauric\Desktop\B.xlsm!A_Tour.A_Tour"`. I think you may just need one `A_Tour` at the end, but I don't know how your modules and procs are named.

Comment: Hi Clauric, If you feel you query is different than what is mentioned in that post then leave a comment here and we will take it from there